# How to collect dates with respect to specific date value in php?

Tags: php, date, comparison

I want to show a message for customer about expiry amount which is expiring this month, so that he can renew it.
Renew time starts from the last month of that expiring amount, that is:

```
$renewDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 month", $currentdate));
```

I have

**Expiry date:** ***Amount***

2019-11-31:   *15*

2019-11-22:   *20*

2020-5-12:    *30*

2019-11-2:    *10*

How can I collect only those amounts which are not less than renew date and are within the range of last one month.

Comment: You need to collect those amounts in php ? In SQL ? if it's in php, you can loop through your `date : amount`, if it's a string you explode by `:` and get one string that you will convert as date + check if < renew date, if it's true you have your amount in the other part of the explode result.

Comment: @MickaëlLeger in PHP. i am using loop, the problem is if condition inside loop which should only select those dates which are with in the range of last month of renew date.. and renew date starts for each amount which is expiring at the end of current month.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the issue. You have these dates, you want to show the ammount of each exp. date, if date -1 month is in the range of today + 1month ?

Comment: @AngelDeykov Exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By playing with @Angel answer I figured it out:

```
  $arr = [
      0=>[
        'date' => '2019-12-1',
        'amount' => 15
      ],
      1=>[
        'date' => '2019-11-31',
        'amount' => 22
      ],
      2=>[
        'date' => '2019-11-27',
        'amount' => 22
      ],
        3=>[
        'date' => '2019-11-12',
        'amount' => 33
      ],
        4=>[
        'date' => '2019-10-2',
        'amount' => 6
      ],
    ];

    $data = [];
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
       if(strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) <= strtotime($value['date']) && 
  strtotime(date('Y-m-d').'+1 month') >= strtotime($value['date']))
       {
          $data[] = $value;
       }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "<pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have an array with expiration dates:

```
$arr = [
  0=>[
    'date' => '2019-12-31',
    'amount' => 15
  ],
  1=>[
    'date' => '2019-12-22',
    'amount' => 22
  ],
    2=>[
    'date' => '2020-5-12',
    'amount' => 33
  ],
    3=>[
    'date' => '2019-10-2',
    'amount' => 6
  ],
];
```

Then we loop through the array, get each date and convert it with strtotime() by substract 1 month and compare it against 2 condition - if date is bigger than strtotime() of todays date and smaller than strtotime() of todays date +1 month we meet the range condition and save the data:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   if(strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) <= strtotime($value['date'].'-1 month') && 
      strtotime(date('Y-m-d').'+1 month') >= strtotime($value['date'].'-1 month'))
   {
      $data[] = $value;
   }
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: as per the above array, $data should be empty as there is no expiry date within the range of today + 1month but it is having 2019-12-31 and 2019-12-22

Comment: range today's date and todays date + 1 mont = from 2019-10-31 to 2019-11-31, so this is our range expire date -1 month is : for '2019-12-31' - 1 month = '2019-11-31' which is bigger or equal from todays date and smaller or equal ftom todays date + 1 month ahead, same for 2019-12-22 -1 month, rest don't meet the conditions

Comment: listen maybe I don't get the criteria you have for getting the array values, the keypoint of my answer is how to use strtotime() by passing date strings +/- 1 month or whatever you need. From here you can play with it to meet the exact criteria for getting the array values ... Cheers